# PHP array uasort

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have the following array with php

```
// array stored in $items    
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [description] => some text
                [value] => 20
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [description] => bord
                [value] => 5
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [description] => axe
                [value] => 99
            )
    )
```

What i want is that the description with bord is alwas the last element. I know that php have the function uasort to write your own custom sort function.

What i've tried is the following

```
uasort($items, function($a, $b){
    if($a['description'] == 'bord'){
      return 0;  
    } 

    return ($a['description'] < $b['description']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

But cant figure out how this works.

**update**
Result after uasort

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => axe
            [value] => 99
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => bord
            [value] => 5
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => some text
            [value] => 20
        )
)
```

If i use the following uasort:

```
uasort($items, function($a, $b){
    if($a['description'] == 'bord'){
      return 1;  
    } 

    return -1;
});
```

The result is correct, but i never used $b.

Comment: If you use var_export on the array and update the question with the results we can copy/paste to duplicate.

Comment: Added some update, after printing with print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uasort` is for associative arrays, but this is not the case with your array. You should use `usort` instead.

```
usort($items, function($a, $b){
    if($a['description'] == 'bord'){
        return 1;  
    } 
   if($b['description'] == 'bord'){
        return -1;  
    } 
    return 0;
});
```

How this works : you want the element with `description` = 'bord' be the last. This means you consider it 'bigger'  than the other elements. You have to return 1 if you consider $a larger, and -1 if you consider $b larger.

Here we return 0 for all other cases, that means that their order will stay the same.

Comment: So if i understood it correctly, When the keys where text instead of numbers i need to use uasort, but now they are numbers so usort instead?

Comment: uasort preserves the keys. It isn't necessarily just for associative arrays since you may have a situation where you want the items to keep their numeric keys as well.

Answer (score 4):

By returning 0 you were telling it to leave the 'bord' item's location alone, and only when it was the first variable ($a) in the comparison. If you want to force it to the bottom you need to tell it how to treat 'bord' in both cases.

```
uasort($items, function($a, $b){
    if($a['description'] == 'bord'){
      return 1;  
    }

    if ($b['description'] == 'bord') {
        return -1;
    }

    return ($a['description'] < $b['description']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Edit: To explain a little more, `uasort()` grabs two elements next to each other in the provided array and assigns them to the $a and $b variables. When your comparison function returns a positive number then it means $a should be moved to a lower position than $b. When it returns a negative number than $a should be higher than $b. When it returns zero then $a and $b are equal.

If I simplify your array a little to `$items = ['some_text', 'bord', 'axe'];` and run a similar uasort function then the steps would look like this:

1. Compare `bord` to `some text`, result = 1

   New order: `['some_text', 'bord', 'axe']`
2. Compare `axe` to `bord`, result = -1

   New order: `['some_text', 'axe', 'bord']`
3. Compare `some text` to `axe`, result = 1

   New order: `['axe', 'some_text', 'bord']`

And that last one is the final result.

Comment: Thx this is working, but still not getting how this works with $a and $b with 1, -1 and 0. Could you try to explain this in some more depth?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($items as $key => $thing) {
if(in_array("bord",$key[description])) { 
    //set aside 
      $last_description=$key[description];
      $last_value=$key[value];
                                           }

$new_array[]=array("description"=>$key[description],"value"=>$key[value];
}    //now, add it back on
$new_array[]=array("description"=>$last_description,"value"=>$last_value);
```

This may get slower with bigger arrays